# Android saving user's choices as favorites

Tags: android, storage

I am developing a music app wherein a user can select choices of songs to play. One feature I want to implement is to save a song as favorite. Once favorite is clicked upon, it should save the user's choice and display it next time when the user logs in. None of the data is stored on the app. Everything is fetched from a server. What I intend to store is just the names of the songs. I read the Android Documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html for various storage options and those which seem applicable to my case are:

- Internal Storage
- Database SQLLite connections

as these will store the data private to the application.

Which among these should I use? Are there any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you populate the song list? Did you have any cache or you just fetch it from the server every time? To improve the performance and be able to use your application when there is no internet connection - at least can view the song you have ,I suggest you have to provide some sort of cache. Once you have the cache, SQLite is the way to go, for both song data and favorite data.

Comment: The list is fetched each time from the server. You are right, I was thinking about trying to store the song list locally too so user can go through it when there is no internet connection.

Comment: Are you recommending that I create a class which acts as cache and can be used to retrieve and store data in the SQLite DB?

Comment: I went for SQLite finally.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them works fine. But since your data will be a single text, i would recommend Shared Preferences, which keeps the data as in XML format and it's easy to use.